# Pattern for a web application

Tags: design-patterns, web-applications, mvc

I'm developing a web application for a university project. My professor wants we to use a multi-tier architecture (Client, Web, Business and Data tiers) with EJB. For the Web and Business I have chosen to use the MVC pattern. Anyway, little by little, I build the tiers in this way: the View (JSP and Servlet) ALWAYS forwards any request from the client to the Controller (Session Beans), which checks if the user can see the page, and if he can it sends to the Servlet the right data (taken from the Entities).

Since the MVC pattern provides an interaction between Model and View, I think that I don't use it (my View interacts only with the Controller). So I'm asking: which is the name for the pattern I'm using? Or is it still the MVC?

Comment: You are confusing View (a collaboration) and Presentation (a layer or tier) :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz Yeah, I'm pretty confused because I've read both articles / docs on the internet and my professor's slides and they say different things. As I can see, the View are JSPs and Servlets (on Web Tier), the Presentation is the client tier (with the browser). Am I right?
I also read the Servlets can be used as Controller, but my professor wants we to use Session Beans (on Business Tier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you may be actually using MVC, or a sort of MVVP, depending on what the entities you pass to the views are.

The views and model may not be interacting directly, but that depends directly on how the view accesses the data it needs (calling certain methods on the model/entities) and how the model implements its logic (which may in fact be a real model implementing data access, just a DTO or maybe a View-Model).

I would say you are still using MVC, but you are on a gray area were several things could be discussed. I could argue that you're still on an area that is MVC-like but could deviate from it.